# Convert full text javascript date

Tags: javascript, date

How do I convert:

```
Wed Jan 10 2018 14:40:39 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
```

to

```
10/01/2018
```

in javascript?

Comment: From where did you got `Wed Jan 10 2018 14:40:39 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)` ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 from `var now = new Date();`

Comment: Then you should be able to pass this string directly to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: This should solve your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/r1mb2dub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
```

Will give you the result you want

Comment: This doesn't solve the question:

Try this: 

`var d = new Date("Wed Jan 10 2018 14:40:39 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)");
d = d.getDate() + '/' + (1 + d.getMonth()) + '/' + d.getFullYear();`

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1mb2dub/

Comment: He wrote he obtained that string doing new Date(), so this solves the question

Comment: He wants it to be `10/01/2018` . Your code will make it to be `01/10/2018` (MM/DD/YYYY).

Comment: Your fiddle gives exactly 10/1/2018

Comment: The format of [*toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tojson) is implementation dependent. Whether the value returned by a particular browser matches the OP's format is just luck. For me, the answer gives "1/10/2018", which is not the format used locally, nor does it match the OP.